# MySQL query with multiple INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a little bit confused about a stupid query:

I get rows from the table **posts** joined with the table **authors** and the table **comments**, in a way like this:

```
SELECT posts.*, authors.name, COUNT(comments.id_post) AS num_comments
FROM posts JOIN authors ON posts.id_author = authors.id_author
LEFT JOIN comments ON posts.id_post = comments.id_post
WHERE posts.active = 1
AND comments.active = 1
```

this doesn't work, of course.

What I try to do is to retrieve:

*1) all my active post (those that were not marked as deleted);*

*2) the names of their authors;*

*3) the number of active comments (those that were not marked as deleted) for each post (if there is at least one);*

What's the way? I know it's a trivial one, but by now my brain is in offside…
Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on "this didn't work"?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, `id_post` uniquely identifies each row in `posts`.  Try this:

```
SELECT p.*, a.name, COUNT(c.id_post) AS num_comments
FROM posts p JOIN
     authors a
     ON p.id_author = a.id_author LEFT JOIN
     comments c
     ON p.id_post = c.id_post
WHERE p.active = 1 AND c.active = 1
GROUP BY p.id_post;
```

Note that this uses a MySQL extension.  In most other databases, you would need to list all the columns in `posts` plus `a.name` in the `group by` clause.

EDIT:

The above is based on your query.  If you want all active posts with a count of active comments, just do:

```
SELECT p.*, a.name, SUM(c.active = 1) AS num_comments
FROM posts p LEFT JOIN
     authors a
     ON p.id_author = a.id_author LEFT JOIN
     comments c
     ON p.id_post = c.id_post
WHERE p.active = 1 
GROUP BY p.id_post;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this way I get back only the posts where there is at least one comment active. Posts with zero comments are ignored…

Comment: My goal is to retrieve all the active posts and the number of comments per post, counting only the comments that are currently **active**.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing a count, you need to have a group by.  So you will need to add

```
Group By posts.*, authors.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You should you GROUP BY clause together with aggregate functions. Try something similar to:

```
SELECT posts.*, authors.name, COUNT(comments.id_post) AS num_comments
FROM posts JOIN authors ON posts.id_author = authors.id_author
LEFT JOIN comments ON posts.id_post = comments.id_post
-- group by
GROUP BY posts.*, authors.name
--
WHERE posts.active = 1
AND comments.active = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct solution:

```
SELECT posts.id_post, authors.name, COUNT(comments.id_post) AS num_comments
FROM posts JOIN authors
ON posts.id_author = authors.id_author
LEFT OUTER JOIN comments
ON (posts.id_post = comments.id_post AND comments.active = 1) 
WHERE posts.active = 1
GROUP BY posts.id_post;
```

Thanks everyone for the help!